# IE11 sometimes renders Arial bold as Arial Black, why?

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-11

I have some rather complicated CSS, but the gist is that I have this:

```
font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
```

There are no other font-weight modifiers in my CSS except `normal` and `bold`. Chrome works just fine.

IE11 -sometimes- renders this as Arial, but other times as Arial Black. This is on the same page. I tested this on our test Windows 8 box, and it is always the same text that ends up in Arial Black.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you sure no other CSS is overriding this? also, make sure `font-variant: normal`

Comment: Every page with this CSS or just one specific page?

Comment: It's a one-page app :)

Comment: What if you replace `font-weight: bold;` with `font-weight: 700;`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is really silly, but I found out why it is happening.

My element was contained in a html `B` element, which gets it's own font-weight in `IE`, overriding the `font-weight` I set.

IE somehow changes the `font` in the `B` element by default. Manually setting `font-weight:bold` fixed the issue.

It looked like this:

```
   <span style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold"><b>text</b></span>
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about the HTML structure you were using? Which elements were contained in which?